# How to have Firefox Widget for Bookmarks?

Tags: app-widgets, firefox-for-android, bookmarks, 8.0-oreo, usability

Google Chrome has own widget for bookmarks, but Android Firefox does not. 
I am thinking how to proceed to do the feature request for the widget.

OS: Oreo 8.0
Phone: Oneplus 3T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firefox doesn't have a bookmarks widget, as stated [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1033995)

You can definitely send your request to them. To do that, open Firefox, go to the menu-> settings -> Mozilla Firefox -> give feedback -> choose one of the options, and you will then have an option of writing in your request.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I'm not in a position to know that. It's up to the app developer to decide what features they want in their app

Comment: You can at least leave your feedback [here](https://qsurvey.mozilla.com/s3/FirefoxInput/?utm_source=feedback-settings)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Btw there are some widget apps that will allow you to save a widget on your home screen and give you the option of opening them with any browser. Never tried them so i can't suggest a good one

Comment: Done. I included the link to this thread in the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I recently switched from Chrome to Firefox and found that the bookmark widget is still not existing in 2022.

So I make one. It is still in beta.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.louislam.firebookmarkwidget